# Passing char array to another function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, char

I am unable to pass a char array from a function to main.

Instead of the actual array, its showing some unwanted symbols. Please help me with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* setDestPath (int x, char inp_path[x])
{
   int ret, cnt=0, i=0, j, temp=0;
   char dest_path[x], out_path[]={'O','U','T','P','U','T','.','b','m','p','\0'};

   while (inp_path[i] !=NULL)
   {
      if (inp_path[i] == '/')
      {
         cnt = i;               
      }
      dest_path[i] = inp_path[i];
      i++;
   }

   for (j=cnt+1;j<x; j++)
   {
      dest_path[j] = NULL;
   }    

   if (cnt > 0)
   {
      for (i=cnt+1; i<=cnt+10; i++)
      {
         dest_path[i] = out_path[temp];
         temp++;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      for (i=cnt; i<cnt+10; i++)
      {
         dest_path[i] = out_path[temp];
         temp++;
      }
   }

   ret = dest_path;
   printf ("\n\nAddress in function is: %d",ret);
   i=0;
   while (i != x)
   {
      printf("\n (%d) %c ", i, dest_path[i]);
      i++;
   }
   return dest_path;
}

int main()
{
   int ch, counter, x=40, temp=0, cnt=0, i=0;
   char inp_path[x], dest_path[x];
   char *path;
   FILE *fp1, *fp2;

   printf("\nEnter the path of image file: \n");
   gets(inp_path);
   path = setDestPath(x, inp_path);
   printf ("\n\nAddress in main is: %d", path);

   while (i != x)
   {
      printf("\n (%d) %c ", i, path[i]);
      i++;
   }

   fp1 = fopen(inp_path, "r+");
   /*remove(dest_path);
     fp2 = fopen(dest_path, "a+");*/

}
```

The array displays correctly inside the setDestPath() but it is not displayed inside main. I am getting some wiered symbols instead.

Output:

```
Enter the path of image file:
g:/project.bmp
Address in function is: 2358448

 (0) g
 (1) :
 (2) /
 (3) O
 (4) U
 (5) T
 (6) P
 (7) U
 (8) T
 (9) .
 (10) b
 (11) m
 (12) p
 (13)
 (14)
 (15)
 (16)
 (17)
 (18)
 (19)
 (20)
 (21)
 (22)
 (23)
 (24)
 (25)
 (26)
 (27)
 (28)
 (29)
 (30)
 (31)
 (32)
 (33)
 (34)
 (35)
 (36)
 (37)
 (38)
 (39)

Address in main is: 2358448
 (0)
 (1)
 (2) ╚
 (3) 6
 (4) √
 (5) ⌂
 (6)
 (7)
 (8)
 (9)
 (10) ╚
 (11) 6
 (12) √
 (13) ⌂
 (14)
 (15)
 (16) 8
 (17) ²
 (18) #
 (19)
 (20)
 (21)
 (22)
 (23)
 (24)
 (25)
 (26) ╚
 (27) 6
 (28) √
 (29) ⌂
 (30)
 (31)
 (32) ☺
 (33)
 (34)
 (35)
 (36)
 (37)
 (38)
 (39)
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Do not use `gets()`, it is very dangerous. Use `fgets`.

Comment: You are returning a local array. That invokes UB since the array gets destroyed once the function ends. BTW, use `%p` to print addresses.

Comment: to print address use `%p` and cast it to `void*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

`dest_path` is an array local to the function. When the function returns, the array is destroyed. By returning `dest_path` from the function as:

```
return dest_path;
```

you are returning a pointer that will be dangling pointer in the calling function. That is cause of your problem. Since you are accessing a dangling pointer, your program is subject to undefined behavior.

You can solve by returning an array that was allocated dynamically using `malloc` or passing an array from `main` and filling it up in the function.

**Solution 1:**

Instead of

```
char dest_path[x];
```

use

```
char* dest_path = malloc(x);
```

And then, make sure that you call

```
free(path);
```

in `main` before the function ends.

**Solution 2:**

Declare an array in `main` and pass in to the function.

```
   char path[1000];   // Make it large enough for your needs.
```

and then use it as:

```
   setDestPath(x, inp_path, path);
```

In order to do that, you'll need to change the function signature to:

```
void setDestPath (int x, char inp_path[x], char dest_path[]) { ... }
```

**PS**

Don't use `gets` at all. Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Thanks. 
kindly let me know why to use fgets instead of gets.

Comment: @saswat23, please follow the link. It has examples.